# How to fix function returning 'none' resulting in unsupported operand for pow()

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to call a my function 'statisticalUncertainty' in my other function 'totalUncertainty'. But when I do the output of statisticalUncertainty returns a number and 'none' which is giving me an error. Why is it returning 'none' when I use it in totalUncertainty, but not when I use it alone?

I've tried not defining typeAUnc and just putting statisticalUncertainty(xdata) directly into my definition of totalUnc, but this still gets the same error.

```
import numpy as np

xdata1=[72.2,77.6,82.4,86.3,88.9]
xdata2=[80.10,81.45,81.50,81.34,82.01]


def statisticalUncertainty(xdata):
   n = len(xdata)
   meanXdata=np.mean(xdata)
   for i in range(1,n):
      innerSum=0
      innerSum=innerSum+(xdata[i]-meanXdata)**2

   std = np.sqrt(innerSum*(1/(n*(n-1))))

   print(std)


def totalUncertainty(xdata,typeBUnc):
   typeAUnc = statisticalUncertainty(xdata)
   totalUnc = 2*(np.sqrt((typeAUnc)**2)+((typeBUnc)**2))

   print(totalUnc)
totalUncertainty(xdata1,0.5)
```

The error I'm getting is:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Comment: `statisticalUncertainty` doesn't explicitly `return` anything, so implicitly returns `None` in `typeAUnc = statisticalUncertainty(xdata)`. Change `print(std)` to `return std`

Answer (score 1):

your function statisticalUncertainty just print value, not returning it.
you should use return instead of print in that function

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a return to your statisticalUncertainty function. This code works fine, and im assuming what you want

```
import numpy as np

xdata1=[72.2,77.6,82.4,86.3,88.9]
xdata2=[80.10,81.45,81.50,81.34,82.01]


def statisticalUncertainty(xdata):
   n = len(xdata)
   meanXdata=np.mean(xdata)
   for i in range(1,n):
      innerSum=0
      innerSum=innerSum+(xdata[i]-meanXdata)**2

   std = np.sqrt(innerSum*(1/(n*(n-1))))

   print(std)
   return std


def totalUncertainty(xdata,typeBUnc):
   typeAUnc = statisticalUncertainty(xdata)
   totalUnc = 2*(np.sqrt((typeAUnc)**2)+((typeBUnc)**2))

   print(totalUnc)
totalUncertainty(xdata1,0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help